# marginbottom isn't working

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="left">
    <a href="index.php">
        <img class="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" width="100%" height="auto" />
    </a>
    <img class="certificates" src="images/certificates.png" alt="Certificates" />
</div>

.left {
    background-image: url("../images/left_background.jpg");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 600px;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 6%;
}

.certificates {
 position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

In that `margin-bottom` isn't working. I want the image always be in the bottom of `<div>`. But I when set `margin_bottom: 5px` nothing happens there. What should I do here?

Comment: You want the image to always be in the bottom of what?

Comment: @fish40: If my answer has been useful to solve your question, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the image to stay on bottom of the `div`, then `margin-bottom` is not what you want at all.

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
```

for `.certificates` will position it inside the div, but only if you add `position: relative;` to the `.left {}`.

Comment: Images are replaced elements, so they are affected by margin properties (and padding properties, which affect non-replaced inline elements, too).

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you're trying to tell me. What do you mean by "replaced"? \\edit: ok, I see... Just never heard that expression. I'll just remove that first part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`margin-bottom` controls only the white space around the image. To put the image at the bottom of the div, use `position:absolute`.